# Using Window Function instead of Select sub-query for counting

Tags: sql-server, join, aggregate, window-functions

I have to count the number of Orders a table, per Employee, for two criteria -

1. "Late Orders".
2. "Total Orders"

The query includes Orders table and Orders table. They are joined together via the `EmployeeID` field. The whole schema is found [here](https://github.com/cimentadaj/sql_practice/blob/master/Northwind2016.bak).

This can be done the following way -

```
    Select E.EmployeeID
        ,E.LastName
        ,(Select Count(*) from Orders where Orders.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID) as AllOrders
        ,count(OrderID) LateOrders

from Orders inner join Employees E on E.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
where CONVERT(date,RequiredDate) <= CONVERT(date,ShippedDate)
group by E.EmployeeID, E.LastName
order by EmployeeID
```

However I want to replace the following row with a window function -

```
    ,(Select Count(*) from Orders where Orders.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID) as AllOrders
```

What I tried to do didn't work, with the following error -

```
Count(*) over(Partition By Orders.EmployeeID)
```

**Column 'Orders.EmployeeID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

I'd like to practice window functions. Can I use it here?

Here's the output -

[image: output]

Comment: Please update your question to include table definitions (DDL), sample data (in the form of insert statements) and the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this would provide the best performance while still avoiding the sub-select.  I guessed that there was a column called OrderID in the Orders table, may need to adjust.

```
;WITH CTE_Orders AS
    (
    SELECT O.EmployeeID
        , COUNT(O.OrderID) AS AllOrders
        , SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, O.RequiredDate) <= CONVERT(DATE, O.ShippedDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LateOrders
    FROM dbo.Orders AS O
    GROUP BY O.EmployeeID
    )
SELECT E.EmployeeID
    , E.LastName
    , C.AllOrders
    , C.LateOrders
FROM CTE_Orders AS C
    INNER JOIN dbo.Employees AS E ON E.EmployeeID = C.EmployeeID
ORDER BY C.EmployeeID
```